# Show map is not a isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Consider $V= \left \{ v= \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3
\end{bmatrix} : x_1-x_2+2x_3=0\right \}\subset K^3$ and the linear map $f:V \rightarrow K^2$ defined by

$f\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1-x_3\\ 
x_2-3x_3
\end{pmatrix}$ ($K$ is just a field)

Show that $f:U \rightarrow K^2$ is **not** a isomorphism

**My try**

I have only been told what a isomorphism is in a general sense; that it has to be "the same" i.e some structure is still the same. For vectors I guess it could be addition, multiplication and the null vector? I am thinking $f$ must be bijective as well. Other than that I have not been taught much more than "it is the same" – which really does not help me in the slightest.

Comment: A (linear) mapping / function $f$ is a bijection if it is injective and surjective. So you have to check those conditions. Obviously, when it is not a bijection, you are done when one of the conditions is not met. So if you conclude it is not injective you do not have to check if it is not surjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

By the rank-nullity theorem, $V$ has dimension $2$, like $K^2$. Hence it is enough to prove that $\ker f$ is non- trivial to prove $f$ is non-injective, and *a fortiori* non-bijective. This means you have to find a non-zero vector $v\in K^3$ such that
\begin{cases} 
x_1-x_2+2x_3=0,\\ 
x_1-x_3=0,\\ 
x_2-3x_3=0.
\end{cases}
You can check that  the kernel of $\varphi:K^3\longrightarrow K^2, \enspace\begin{pmatrix}x_1\cr x_2\cr x_3\end{pmatrix}\longmapsto\begin{pmatrix}x_1-x_3\cr x_2-3x_3\end{pmatrix}$ ($\,f$ is its restriction to $V$) is actually contained in $V$, so you only have to determine a basis of $\ker \varphi$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117479/discussion-on-answer-by-bernard-show-map-is-not-a-isomorphism).

Comment: My apologies. I have stated my concerns in the chat now, @Bernard

Answer (score 1):

Your notion is actually correct. Observe that for all $x \in V, x_1 - x_2 + 2 x_3 = 0$ which implies  $x_1 - x_3 = x_2- 3 x_3 $ . Thus, this map is not surjective as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you have been thinking of, is correct.
Here, the map $f$ is between the vector space $V$ and the field $K^2$, hence, we are asked to show that $f$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces.
(I leave it to you to check that $V$ is indeed a vector space)

Now, an isomorphism between vector spaces is nothing but an injective and a subjective map, i.e. a bijection between them. Here, it is enough to show that it is *not* either one of them.

**Hint**: Show that $f$ is *not* injective. Can you use the relation between $ x_1,x_2,$ and $x_3$ in the definition of $V$, to write the image of $f$ as something that gives you this?

Comment: so $x_1-x_2+2x_3=0\Leftrightarrow x_2-3x_3=x_1-x_3$?

Comment: Yes, now, do you see that the $Image(f)$ is independent of $x_2$. Can $f$ be injective now?

Comment: I think since it is independent any $x_2$ will give me the same image if the other variables are fixed and thus it is not injective. But I do not see how it is independent?

Comment: What is the Image now? just write it down and you are done.
What is the meaning of *Image is Independent of $x_2$* ?

Comment: I am not sure what I am asked and what the process is. Why is it independent of $x_2$ when $x_2-3x_3=x_1-x_3$?

Comment: image is the elements in the codomain i.e the output values of $f$

Comment: Yes, precisely, the image is of $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ is $\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 - x_3\\ 
x_1 - x_3\\ 

\end{pmatrix} $, which doesn't contain (/independent of) $x_2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117457/discussion-between-adithya-s-and-mathstudent23).

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(1,1,0),(-2,0,1)\in V$, that $f(1,1,0)=(1,1)$, and that $f(-2,0,1)=(-3,3)$. Therefore, $f(-3,-3,0)=f(-2,0,1)\bigl(=(-3,3)\bigr)$ and so $f$ is not injective. It follows that $f$ is not an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $V$ is the null space of the rank-1 matrix $[1 \hspace{0.3cm} -1 \hspace{0.3cm} 2]$. So $V$ is 2 dimensional vector space and any linearly independent two vectors from $V$ can be a basis. Select $v=(1,1,0)$ and $w=(0,2,1)$ in $V$. They are lin independent so $\{v,w\}$ can be a basis of $V$.

$\textbf{Fact:}$ $\{fv,fw\}$ can be a basis for $K^2$ iff $f$ is isomorphism.

But $fv=f(1,1,0)=(1,1)$ and $fw=f(0,2,1)=(-1,-1)$.So they are linearly $\textbf{dependent}$ and they cannot be a basis. By the fact above we showed $f$ is not be an isomorphism.